# Get Var() and AVG() from many columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm building a query to show average and variance from many columns.

To get the average I use this:

```
SELECT *,
   (SELECT AVG(t.c)
    FROM   (
            SELECT peca_1 UNION ALL
            SELECT peca_2 UNION ALL
            SELECT peca_3 UNION ALL
            SELECT peca_4 UNION ALL
            SELECT peca_5 UNION ALL
            SELECT peca_6 UNION ALL
            SELECT peca_7 UNION ALL
            SELECT peca_8 UNION ALL
            SELECT peca_9 UNION ALL
            SELECT peca_10
                  )  t(c)
    )  as [media]
from Durabilidade
where cd_durabilidade = 1
```

The result is:

[image]

Now I need a new column with VAR(media) comparing each row with first row.

Any idea?

Comment: I think I'll need a store procedure or a function..                      

Because I'll need to calculate like this:

 average(current_row) - average(first_row) / (average(first_row) * 100 

I made this in C# but I want in sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a case where `cross apply` is appropriate.  I am assuming that you want the variance of the values as calculated by the `var()` function:

```
SELECT *, t.avgval as [media], t.varval
from Durabilidade d cross apply
     (select avg(t.val) as avgval, var(t.val) as varval
      from (select d.peca_1 union all
            select d.peca_2 union all
            select d.peca_3 union all
            select d.peca_4 union all
            select d.peca_5 union all
            select d.peca_6 union all
            select d.peca_7 union all
            select d.peca_8 union all
            select d.peca_9 union all
            select d.peca_10
           ) t(val) -- t(val) to work
     ) t
where cd_durabilidade = 1
```

Comment: Thank you @Gordon!! I not know "cross apply".
It's work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT *,
  VAR(media) AS [variance]
FROM
(    
 SELECT *,
   (SELECT AVG(t.c)
    FROM   (
            SELECT peca_1 UNION ALL
            SELECT peca_2 UNION ALL
            SELECT peca_3 UNION ALL
            SELECT peca_4 UNION ALL
            SELECT peca_5 UNION ALL
            SELECT peca_6 UNION ALL
            SELECT peca_7 UNION ALL
            SELECT peca_8 UNION ALL
            SELECT peca_9 UNION ALL
            SELECT peca_10
                  )  t(c)
    )  as [media]
 from Durabilidade
 where cd_durabilidade = 1
) x
GROUP BY
 column1_from_durabilidade
 ,column2_from_durabilidade
 --etc
 ,media
```

Comment: I was tried something like that, but the only result I got is a blank column.

Your version not working here, I got a error: 
" Column 'x.cd_med_durabilidade' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. "

Comment: Oh right, VAR is an aggregate function, then you'll need to group by all the other columns from the subselect also

Comment: Ok @NickyvV!! Thank you, now it's running but the column (variance) is blank (NULL)  
I think I'll need a store procedure or a function..  

Because I'll need to calculate like this: 
average(current_row) - average(first_row) / (average(first_row) * 100   

I made this in C# but I want in sql server